# using JSX file format instead of JS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-code

I'm VSCode user , it is frustrating to define language when ever you close file tab and opening again,all the time! in react projects.

so I tried to chage my `header.js` to `header.jsx` and it worked and I don't need to define language all the time.

but I wonder if it is good practice or not , all of my syntaxes and snippets seems working.

can I use `jsx` file format instead of JS in my react projects?

Comment: I don't have to do that; I just open a .js file and everything works as expected. Can you post your package.json?

Comment: @ChrisG everything is working yes , until you close your js file and reopen again and it's language will change to plain javascript again

Comment: What exactly do you mean by that? Is your JSX getting marked as syntax error? Like I said, I can close .js files and open them again, and all is fine. In VSCode. I'm using create-react-app though, which probably sets up linting accordingly.

Comment: @ChrisG yes and also Emmett is not working unless you define language from command pallete again

Comment: Right, I suspect you need an `esLintConfig` setup in your package.json; do you have that?

Comment: @ChrisG sorry for late answering,  I have it , it is something like this: `"eslintConfig": { "extends" : "react-app"}`

Comment: I recommend you to use always `js` instaed of `jsx`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the .jsx, if you are creating React Components with HTML code (e.g. Components, html tags etc, then use .js for pure javascript code only like creating utils and etc.

Comment: I think the question is about why VS Code does not work well when the file extension is `js`, and how to fix that.

Comment: when I'm closing js file which defined as `javascript react` and reopening it , it's language definition changing to plain js again and emmet is not working

Comment: @IhateReact If this answer didn't solve your actual problem, why did you mark it as accepted?

Comment: @ChrisG I didn't,  I think it was touch problem,  I'm  on tablet right now

Answer (score 0):

You should use .jsx if you have React components, or simpler HTML tags in the file.

You could use js if in your file are only React hooks or functions that don't depend on the react.js library.

Comment: But jsx also working with hooks and Functions

Comment: Right, but there is no sense, since you don't need JSX syntax support.

Comment: React hooks and rendering Functions are coming from react isn't?

Comment: like usestate hook from react

Comment: Yes, but you need .JSX syntax only in renders case, otherwise, you don't need it. For useCallback, useEffect, useMemo you don't need JSX support. Only if you have any HTML tags if that file.